# What's the meaning of `------rwx`

Tags: linux

I know the last three characters indicate that everyone has permission to R/W/X. Who's everyone? Does everyone contain user and group members? If not, why we want such a mode? Could anyone give me an example I need it?

Comment: [There are three sets of read/write/execute permissions: one set for the **user** of the file, one set for the **group** of the file, and one set for **everyone else** (other).](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Permissions.html#uh-0)

Comment: Wrong site!  Try superuser.com.

Answer (score 5):

```
   + ------------------ User Permissions Read
   | + ---------------- User Permissions Write
   | | + -------------- User Permissions Execute
   | | | + ------------ Group Permissions Read
   | | | | + ---------- Group Permissions Write
   | | | | | + -------- Group Permissions Execute
   | | | | | | + ------ Other Permissions Read
   | | | | | | | + ---- Other Permissions Write
   | | | | | | | | + -- Other Permissions Execute
   | | | | | | | | |
   r w x r w x r w x

   User Permissions: The user that own the file.
   Group Permissions: The group the file belongs to.
   Other Permissions: The other users i.e. everyone else.
```

Answer (score 1):

They are permissions on a file or directory...

These permissions are divided into `user/group/other` with `read, write and execute` permissions.

When you do ls -l you get a output something like this

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4096 Feb 26 10:58 bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   26156 Jan 14 09:21 sleep
```

In this the first set start with `d`, this field indicates a file type i.e, whether it is a directory/socket/regular file/pipe file etc.,(`-` indicates a regular file).

The second set is a series of 9 fields which actually indicates the file access permissions.

The first three indicates the permissions for the user/owner, here

- `r` indicates a read permission,
- `w` indicates a write permission
- `x` indicates a execute permission
- `-` indicates that particular permission is not available to the user.

The other six values indicates the permission to group and others. Whose meaning is same as that of user permissions.

For more information you can read this complete tutorial
[here](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions).